# How to select data from an sql table ordered by datetime_received but only for the current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select specific data only for the current date.

My query is

```
sql="""
SELECT * from table where company_name ='XXX' 
AND company_id != 0 ORDER BY datetime_recieved 
"""
```

I don't know what else to add, so it always selects only the current date.

Comment: You need to add a current date condition to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want that `datetime_recieved` is current date:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE company_name ='XXX' AND company_id != 0 AND DATE(datetime_recieved) = DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY datetime_recieved
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to checkmark the response